# Is it possible to build this kind of iOS Bluetooth app?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, bluetooth

I want to know if it is possible to build this kind of bluetooth application on iOS platform.

There are two devices:
   1. bluetooth device with installed camera module
          - This device only has a camera module, a memory, and a bluetooth module.
   2. iOS device. (sleeping - with screen black, possibly locked)

The bluetooth device can be used to do the following:
   1. Press a button to take a picture
   2. Send the picture via bluetooth to the Iphone,
   3. Iphone wakes up, sends the picture to a server.

The key points that I'm curious about is
   1. Is is possible to wake up the device with a bluetooth signal,
   2. Is it possible to launch an application/wake up an application with a bluetooth signal so that it can process information/send it?

Also, if this functionality is possible, then can it be done with classic bluetooth module, without registering for the MFI program? or do I have to use BLE?

Comment: I think you can do all these stuff in a jail broken iPhone.

Comment: First thing your ques is not clear i.e what are your device capable of i.e it is a BLE or non BLE device.So i am trying to mention some techniques which can be helpful..

Answer (score 5):

**Techniques to discover the device:**

**1. Core Bluetooth Framework:** only works for Bluetooth low energy i.e BLE.

**2. EAaccessory Framework:** Apple provides an API called External Accessory Framework, which can be used to interact with paired Bluetooth devices or device connected through wired, for which we have to fix the apple connector at the base of the device.

**3. Gamekit Framework:** if we are using game kit framework then it is necessary that the application is running in foreground in both of the device i.e if the application is in background then it is not possible to pear the device and second thing if we are using game kit framework then there is a limit of about 90k per 'send' ,so if our file is larger then 90k then we have to break it up.

If you have any queries then you can ask..

Comment: Thank you for answering! Let me make myself clearer! I'm trying to use the Core Bluetooth Framework(BLE). When I press the camera button on my external device, I want that device to make my iphone execute some code. How would I achieve that?